# uv tiling and offset for uvs not min-max 0-1

Tags: procedural-generation, graphics-programming, uv-mapping

For the purpose of the question, a unit = 1 meter.

So, I have a triangle strip that is 4x8 meters (for argument's sake; it is procedurally generated by player). I also have a texture which is 512x512px.

For normal UV mapping, I just make U 0 or 1 (depending on the side of the strip), and I make V a value normalized between 0 and 1, based on the distance "traveled" along the strip.

Then I set tiling based on the distance, and the texture. In this case, the tiling would be 2 along Y, since the texture is a square.

I am having trouble dealing with a scenario where I do NOT use UV 0 to 1 though. I only want to sample the "middle" of the texture,. such that the min/max of the UV coords are 0.0x0.25 to 1.0x0.75.

When I try to make this work, I notice that as I lay my strip (done by player in game; mesh updates continually during placement), the texture moves along the strip. I figure I need to adjust the offset, but I am having difficulty figuring out the formula to use to determine what the offset should be based on the tiling (which in turn is based on the length of the strip).

when the tiling is 1, there is no problem with the offset (0). A tiling of 3 is also correct with no offset. Same for tiling 5, 7, etc. Odd numbers basically. When the tiling is an even number though, or a fractional number, offset 0 no longer works. On top of that, the needed offset seems to change based on the tiling.

How would one go about calculating this?

In addition, if I lay two of these strips end to end, and I want the texture to be continuous; how would one calculate the offset based on the tiling/offset of the previous strip behind it?

Comment: A drawing would probably help understanding your question. Attaching one would likely increase your chances for answer.